# MySQL data to Excel only in one column when exporting using PHPExcel

Tags: php, mysql, substring, phpexcel

I'm trying to seperate my data from MySQL to an excel file using PHPExcel. I want the data to separated by rows. 
For example,

Detail1 Response1 Status1 

Detail2 Response2 Status2

Detail3 Response3 Status3

The Delimiter for the data is **||** and the seperator for each line is **::**

Here's the **data**:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
<?php 


try {

$sql = "SELECT ID,DESCRIPTION FROM SAMPLE";


} catch (Exception $ex) {
          echo 'Message: ' .$ex->getMessage();
  }  

   $connect = @mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) 

or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno()); 
//select database 
$Db = @mysql_select_db($dbname, $connect) 
or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno()); 
//execute query 
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$connect) 
or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno()); 

error_reporting(E_ALL);


require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';

// Execute the database query
// Instantiate a new PHPExcel object 
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();  
// Set the active Excel worksheet to sheet 0 
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); 

$rowCount = 2;


$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'ID');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', 'DESCRIPTION');

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['ID']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['DESCRIPTION']);

    }


header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="SampleExcel.xls"'); 
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); 
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5'); 
$objWriter->save('php://output');

?>
```

**Update**

I now have progress on how to approach on my problem :) I've used MySQL query to create a separator and my data are now placed in rows.

**Result**
[image]

Now, the one I would like now is to separate them with the delimiter being '||'. Can you help me with this?

**Here's my query:**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SELECT sample.id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sample.DESCRIPTION, '::', numbers.n), '::', -1) as name FROM numbers INNER JOIN sample ON CHAR_LENGTH(sample.DESCRIPTION) -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(sample.DESCRIPTION, '::', ''))>=numbers.n-1,'||'-2) as string
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you are incrementing the variable `$rowCount`.

You should write `++$rowCount;` inside your while loop just at the end of it.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['ID']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['DESCRIPTION']);

++$rowCount;
}
```

Comment: I have used $rowCount = 2, to get the positioning of the excel cell. And I think I don't need the ++rowCount because I'm using a while loop here.Meaning I'm getting the results of my query even if I have 5 of them. It will get all the results as long as there are records matching my query.

Comment: But you are always writing the row output at Excel row 2 if you don't increment it. Please see my code.